# Serving static files in Cowboy (Erlang)

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I read this guide https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.0/guide/static_files/ and I implement

`{"/assets/[...]", cowboy_static, {dir, "/var/www/assets"}}`

in my `tunnel_app.erl` file:

```
-module(tunnel_app).
-behaviour(application).

-export([start/2]).
-export([stop/1]).

start(_Type, _Args) ->
  Dispatch = cowboy_router:compile([
    {'_', [
    {"/info", lobby_handler, []},
    {"/join/:name", join_handler, []},
    {"/player/status/:name", player_status_handler, []},
    {"/tables/info/:table_id", table_info_handler, []},
    {"/tables/play/:table_id/:name/:auth/:action/:x/:y", table_play_handler, []},
    {"/assets/[...]", cowboy_static, {dir, "/static/assets"}}
    ]}]),
  {ok, _} = cowboy:start_clear(my_http_listener, 100,
    [{port, 8080}],
    #{env => #{dispatch => Dispatch}}),
  {ok, MainDoor} = door:go(),
  register(main_door, MainDoor),
  {ok, MainRoom} = room:go(),
  register(main_room, MainRoom),
  tunnel_sup:start_link().

stop(_State) ->
    ok.
```

I have my files in `static/assets`:

```
~/tunnel/ls static
assets
~/tunnel/ls static/assets
actions.js      dashboard.js        hole.js         player.js       tableview.js
board.js        display.js      http.min.js     script.js       tile.js
callback.js     engine.js       info.js         style.css       view.js
client.js       engine_client.js    moves           table.js
clock.js        game.html       notes           tablemaster.js
color.js        ground.js       oboard.js       tableproxy.js
~/tunnel/
```

When I navigate to

`http://localhost:8080/assets/game.html`

My browser gets a 404.

EDIT:

The root path of the project is `/users/quantum/tunnel` with `/users/quantum/tunnel/src` being where all the `.erl files live.

I tried changing the path to `"{"/assets/[...]", cowboy_static, {dir, "/users/quantum/tunnel/src/static/assets/"}}"`

and navigating to `localhost:8080/assets/game.html` shows nothing (not even 404)

Aha! I made a mistake in the path - static is in the root of the project, not inside src.

`{"/assets/[...]", cowboy_static, {dir, "../static/assets/"}}` does not work nor does `static/assets`, however:

`{"/assets/[...]", cowboy_static, {dir, "/users/quantum/tunnel/static/assets/"}}` does work.

Comment: Can you try putting the absolute path of the folder? (or remove the leading slash might also work).

Comment: Removing the leading slash: `{dir, "static/assets"}}`, I still get 404. Changing to `{"/assets/[...]", cowboy_static, {dir, "~/tunnel/static/assets"}}`, I also get 404 when I navigate to `localhost:8080/assets/game.html`

Comment: By absolute path I meant `/home/<your username>/tunnel/static/assets` or whatever the full path to that folder is on your disk. `"static/assets"` should work if that's the relative path from the root of your Erlang application. What's the root folder of your Erlang application?

Comment: @Dogbert I mistook the `tunnel/src` for `tunnel/` . I run `gmake run` from `~/tunnel` but the erlang files are in `~/tunnel/src`. See my edit above^ a full path including `/users` fixes the issue